# Query to calculate number of active jobs

Tags: sql, mysql

There is a `jobs` table,

| jobID | state | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | inProgress | 2023-11-02 10:39:37 |
| 1 | some random log | 2023-11-02 10:40:37 |
| 2 | inProgress | 2023-11-02 10:43:37 |
| 1 | inProgress | 2023-11-02 10:44:37 |
| 1 | inProgress | 2023-11-02 10:45:37 |
| 1 | inProgress | 2023-11-02 10:50:00 |
| 1 | end | 2023-11-02 11:40:37 |
| 1 | inProgress | 2023-11-02 11:43:37 |
| 1 | inProgress | 2023-11-02 11:44:37 |
| 1 | end | 2023-11-02 11:45:37 |
| 2 | some random log | 2023-11-02 11:50:37 |
| 2 | end | 2023-11-02 12:00:37 |

I would like to

1. calculate how many jobs are in progress (i.e. has already started but not end yet)

I first thought I could calculate `count(state=inProgress)-count(state=end)`  to get the number of inProgress jobs but `inProgress` could show up not only once.

2. get execution duration for each finished job

Note that a job can execute multiple times, exg. `jobID1` executed from start to finish twice, therefore two execution durations need to be calculated for `jobID1`.

`jobID1` execution duration is  `time diff between 2023-11-02 11:40:37, 2023-11-02 10:39:37` AND `time diff between 2023-11-02 11:45:37, 2023-11-02 11:43:37`

`jobID2` execution duration is `time diff between 2023-11-02 12:00:37, 2023-11-02 10:43:37`

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: Maybe `SUM(IF(state='inProgress',1,0))-SUM(IF(state='end',1,0))`. By the way, what is your `timestamp` datatype? And how do you plan to get the execution time using those values?

Comment: @FanoFN - just doing a straight SUM doesn't take into account that the jobs are logging multiple instances of "inProgress" as they go along.  Going by the OP's sample data table, your formula would have a result of "3", whereas actually there are current zero active jobs

Comment: Another thing is, shouldn't your `jobID` consists of same id for a single `inProgress` + `end` combo? Your sample data is showing 4 `inProgress` state for `jobID=1`, so which one should take into consideration when calculating the execution time?

Comment: @FanoFN - to me, the "timestamp" appears to be the number of hours/minutes since a job started.  (Which, in reality, means that reporting the "Execution Time" is just taking the "timestamp" value from the "end" log record)

Comment: I get that @Craig, that's why I said maybe and didn't bother posting an answer. I have follow up question about the data as well. However, doing the sum formula would at least return a result than doing `count(state=inProgress)-count(state=end)`.

Comment: Maybe you're right but maybe it's just a typo or something. Only OP knows that so let's wait for a reply.

Comment: The count of jobs in progress could be obtained with ``SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT j1.jobID) FROM jobs j1 LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs j2 ON j2.jobID = j1.jobID AND j2.state = 'end' WHERE j1.state = 'inProgress' AND j2.jobID Is Null``

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The timestamp is hour:second. If there are multiple in progress records for the same jobID, it should calculate timestamp at the end - timestamp at the first inProgress

Comment: Are you sure it's hour:second? not hour:minute?

Comment: @GigiWithoutHadid - what particular need is there to "calculate" the execution time?  Isn't the value that's recorded on the "end" log record the total duration of the job?

Comment: Sorry it's minute:second. (On my phone now..) the execution time means how long it takes the job from run to finish. Sorry the question wasn't phrased very well. It's a real life problem I kinda abstracted and simplified into the example. The real life problem is we have a logger that emits logs of our jobs. It emits "inProgress state" logs multiple times we want to know how long it took the job to finish

Comment: @GigiWithoutHadid - that still doesn't necessarily explain what the "timestamp" values signify .... is it the number of minutes and seconds since the job started?  Is is the number of minutes and seconds since the last log record was created?

Comment: I realize my example is confusing, so I updated the timestamp values. It is the current time

Comment: @GigiWithoutHadid , see this fiddle example https://dbfiddle.uk/CGX6HxGW

Comment: Thanks for the link that looks great! However I just updated the description. It has one more tricky part. A jobID could finish a complete execution multiple times (See updated description)

Comment: @GigiWithoutHadid - I'll be honest, now this is getting to be a lot of "free" work to do ..... you so far haven't included any of your actual query attempts.

Comment: @craig tbh I just learned inner join, outer join, very new at SQL. The algorithm would be like "find record with state == end" then go through all the records with timestamp smaller than that, get the earliest inProgress state record then calculate the diff". I imagine it would be like a stored procedure? A simple query couldn't do it probably. Honestly it's too difficult for a newbie like me. I have tried many times (with lots of syntax errors lol). I need it for a personal project I am hoping to launch soon. Honestly I don't mind tipping... Not hoping for free work really

Comment: @FanoFN updated sample data for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE jobs(
  jobID INT,
  state VARCHAR(50),
  timestamp datetime);

INSERT INTO jobs VALUES
(1, 'inProgress', '2023-11-02 10:39:37'),
(1, 'some random log', '2023-11-02 10:40:37'),
(2, 'inProgress', '2023-11-02 10:43:37'),
(1, 'inProgress', '2023-11-02 10:44:37'),
(1, 'inProgress', '2023-11-02 10:45:37'),
(1, 'inProgress', '2023-11-02 10:50:00'),
(1, 'end', '2023-11-02 11:40:37'),
(1, 'inProgress', '2023-11-02 11:43:37'),
(1, 'inProgress', '2023-11-02 11:44:37'),
(1, 'end', '2023-11-02 11:45:37'),
(2, 'some random log', '2023-11-02 11:50:37'),
(2, 'end', '2023-11-02 12:00:37');
```

Based on the data sample above, here is a suggestion:

```
WITH end_state AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY jobID, timestamp) AS Rsnum,
         jobID, timestamp AS end_time
  FROM jobs 
  WHERE state='end'),
  es_wDelimiter AS (
SELECT e1.*, 
       IF(e2.end_time < e1.end_time, e2.end_time,NULL) AS esDelimiter
FROM end_state e1
LEFT JOIN end_state e2 ON e1.jobID=e2.jobID AND e1.end_time <> e2.end_time)

SELECT Rsnum,
       j.jobID,
       MIN(timestamp) AS StartTime,
       MAX(end_time) AS EndTime,
       TIMEDIFF(MAX(end_time),MIN(timestamp)) AS ExecutionTime
FROM jobs j 
 LEFT JOIN es_wDelimiter e
ON j.jobID=e.jobID 
AND j.timestamp > IFNULL(esDelimiter,0)
AND j.timestamp <= e.end_time
GROUP BY Rsnum, j.jobID
ORDER BY RsNum, j.jobID;
```

The query operation are as following:

1. Get all timestamp with state=end and assign with row number - the row numbers are used as new group.
2. Wrap the first query as common table expression and do another query to create
   a custom delimiter.
3. wrap the second query as another common table expression and do a LEFT JOIN query
   to it with jobs table with these conditions:

- `jobs.timestamp` value is larger than the delimiter value that been set earlier (if the delimiter value is NULL then it will be assigned with `0`).
- `jobs.timestamp` value is smaller or the same as the `end_time` value we
  extracted from the first query.

Here is a fiddle for reference: https://dbfiddle.uk/RBEHLuji

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! If you'd like, email me at `justforraphls1@gmail.com` there are paid opportunities for questions like this for my projects

Comment: Glad I could help and thanks for the opportunity, I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

For a job that may have multiple instances the following approach "looks backward" to locate any previous ends for the same jobid, each instance of the jobid is also assigned using `row_number()`. Then these rows for "ends" are then joined to any rows representing "In Progress" with conditions to ensure they fit within "previous end" (or NULL) and "this end". Then the minimum start of each job instance is calculated, and the duration (in seconds) also made available.

```
WITH e AS (
    SELECT
          id
        , jobid
        , LAG(TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY jobID ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS prev_end
        , TIMESTAMP AS end_time
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY jobid ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS job_inst
    FROM jobs
    WHERE STATE = 'end'
    )
SELECT
      e.jobid
    , e.job_inst
    , min(p.start_time) start_time
    , e.end_time
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min(p.start_time), e.end_time) AS du_seconds
FROM e
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
          id
        , jobID
        , TIMESTAMP AS start_time
    FROM jobs
    WHERE STATE = 'inProgress'
    ) p ON e.jobid = p.jobid 
      AND (
               (p.start_time < e.end_time and e.prev_end IS NULL)
             OR
               (p.start_time > e.prev_end and p.start_time < e.end_time)
             )
GROUP BY
     e.jobid
   , e.job_inst
   , e.end_time
ORDER BY
     e.jobid
   , e.job_inst
```

| jobid | job_inst | start_time | end_time | du_seconds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-11-02 10:39:37 | 2023-11-02 11:40:37 | 3660 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-11-02 11:43:37 | 2023-11-02 11:45:37 | 120 |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-11-02 10:43:37 | 2023-11-02 12:00:37 | 4620 |

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PsSxLpNI)

Once you have the jobs and instances of them available, the min/max start/end and  total duration can be easily calculated from the result seen above (optionally the max(job_inst) could also be displayed).

```
SELECT
      jobid
    , MAX(job_inst)
    , MIN(start_time)
    , MAX(end_time)
    , SUM(du_seconds)
FROM (
       { result from above }
     ) d
GROUP BY
      jobid
```